# Why is mongoexport producing malformed JSON?

Tags: json, mongodb

I am exported my mongo collections. But when importing them mongo says they are malformed JSON.

```
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Putting the data through a JSON validator I get.

```
Error: Parse error on line 14:
...17:33:54.726Z"   }} {    "_id": {        "$oid"
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

1. What is wrong with the JSON above?
2. Whey would Mongo export malformed JSON?

Comment: The format is actually meant for "large" output which you would read from a stream as "chunks" ( basically what `mongoimport` does ). If you are expecting a *"one hit file slurp"* ( not recommended ) then there is the [`--jsonArray`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption--jsonArray) option, which gives you exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoexport produces rows of JSON, not a single JSON file.  Each line that mongoexport is producing is its own JSON document. If you put the whole file in a JSON validator, it is trying to validate multiple JSON documents as if it were a single file.

That would be the same as validating

```
{ "test": 1 }
{ "test": 2 }
```

(which is not a valid single JSON document)

sometimes this format is also called [JSONL](http://jsonlines.org)

Try validating a each line of JSON produced by mongoexport individually.

Comment: I am getting the same error from MongoDB Compass tool. It says the JSON that MongoDB exported is not valid and contains errors. I put the JSON through a separate validator for a sanity check.

Comment: With the MongoDB Compass I get this error Unexpected token N in JSON at position 1255

Comment: Could you ask that as a different question please?